# Silent Installation of appserv-win32-2.5.10

Tags: c#, process, installation, silent, appserver

i need to install 'appserv-win32-2.5.10.exe' from basic c# desktop application
by predefined values of argument like server , root password etc.
i found this code that used to Silent install from c# by sending my predefined argument to the installation process . the question is how can i get the argument name for this application  ''appserv-win32-2.5.10.exe''

```
int exitcode;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = @"server\appserv-win32-2.5.10.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
/// startInfo.Arguments = "/s /v/qn"; // Arguments 
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            exitcode = exeProcess.ExitCode;
            MessageBox.Show("exitcode:" + exitcode);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you asking what the valid arguments are for that executable?  What does c# have to do with this?

Comment: yes, i am asking about the valid arguments .

Comment: You're going to need to read the docs for appserv_win32-2.5.10.exe then.  It's got nothing to do with C#.  What is that executable?  Who is the vendor?